# ВозбУдить или возбудИть (уголовное дело) — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

*Уголовное дело **возбУждено** или **возбужденО**?

Он **возбУдит** или он **возбудИт** уголовное дело?*

Как правильно?

Comment: Возбу*ждают? Вам не показалось?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас, как и прежде, общелитратурная норма: возбужд**а**ть,возбуд**и**ть,возбуж**у** возбуд**и**т.

Вот что говорит  «Словарь трудностей произношения и ударения в современном русском языке. - СПб.: "Норинт".. К.С. Горбачевич. 2000.»

возбуд**и**ть, возбуж**у**, возбуд**и**т (*не рекомендуется возб**у**дит;* *встречается в речи юристов*).

Т. е. это так называемый профессиональный жаргон юристов.

Ср. другие слова из профеесонального жаргона.

до́быча (в профессиональном жаргоне геологов); **а**лкоголь (в речи медиков); комп**а**с (в речи моряков).

Comment: никогда раньше не слышал слово "до́быча", а вот остальные примеры из вашего ответа довольно популярны у народа.